# Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a running `soap` webservice client application.
All of a sudden I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[...]
```

From the logs I can see that received `Content-Type: text/xml` in the past. But now I'm just getting the error above.

What might be the problem here? Can't cxf handle the returned contentType `text/html`? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Ideally it should be text/xml so was there are change at server side?

Comment: Indeed it was a change on the serverside, as this shouldn't be the case, as was fixed now in the meantime.